# Scala Circe cannot decode model with list as member

Tags: scala, serialization, deserialization, quill, decoder

I have a model, containing a list as a member variable, that I am trying to serialize using Circe in Scale.

The model in question -

```
case class Order(id: Long, tableId: Long, items: List[Item]) {

}

object Order {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Order] = deriveEncoder[Order]

  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Order] = deriveDecoder[Order]
}
```

Also, the Item class -

```
case class Item(id: Long, name: String, serving: String) {

}

object Item {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Item] = deriveEncoder[Item]

  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Item] = deriveDecoder[Item]
}
```

I am using Circe's semi-auto encoder feature. However, when trying to read data from the database using quill, I am encountering this exception -

```
[error] /Users/in-rmoitra/Projects/PetProjects/Restrofit-Backend/src/main/scala/models/repository/OrderRepository.scala:17:69: exception during macro expansion:
[error] scala.reflect.macros.TypecheckException: Can't find implicit `Decoder[List[models.Item]]`. Please, do one of the following things:
[error] 1. ensure that implicit `Decoder[List[models.Item]]` is provided and there are no other conflicting implicits;
[error] 2. make `List[models.Item]` `Embedded` case class or `AnyVal`.
[error]
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.$anonfun$typecheck$3(Typers.scala:32)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.$anonfun$typecheck$2(Typers.scala:26)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.doTypecheck$1(Typers.scala:25)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.$anonfun$typecheck$7(Typers.scala:38)
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.wrappingIntoTerm(Trees.scala:1731)
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.wrappingIntoTerm$(Trees.scala:1728)
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.wrappingIntoTerm(SymbolTable.scala:18)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.typecheck(Typers.scala:38)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.typecheck$(Typers.scala:20)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Context.typecheck(Context.scala:6)
[error]     at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Context.typecheck(Context.scala:6)
[error]     at io.getquill.context.QueryMacro.expandQueryWithMeta(QueryMacro.scala:41)
[error]     at io.getquill.context.QueryMacro.expandQuery(QueryMacro.scala:20)
[error]     at io.getquill.context.QueryMacro.runQuery(QueryMacro.scala:12)
[error]     val ordersFuture: Future[List[(Order, (OrderItem, Item))]] = run(query)
```

From my limited knowledge of Circe and what I already looked up, the docs say that you do not need to create a decoder for List[A] if you already have a decoder for [A].

It would be great if someone could throw light on what seems to be happening here.

Answer (score 2):

Your Circe code is fine. If you execute

```
println(
      parse("""
              |{ "id" : 1,
              |  "tableId" : 2,
              |  "items" : [
              |     { "id": 3,
              |       "name" : "a",
              |       "serving" : "b"
              |     },
              |     { "id": 4,
              |       "name" : "c",
              |       "serving" : "d"
              |     }
              |  ]
              |}
            """.stripMargin)
        .flatMap(json => json.as[Order])
    )
```

you'll get

```
Right(Order(1,2,List(Item(3,a,b), Item(4,c,d))))
```

So the trouble is in your Quill code.

And don't confuse `io.circe.Decoder` and `io.getquill.context.jdbc.Decoders#Decoder`.

https://getquill.io/#extending-quill-custom-encoding

[`exception during macro expansion: [error] scala.reflect.macros.TypecheckException` when using quill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550851/exception-during-macro-expansion-error-scala-reflect-macros-typecheckexcepti)